# Should we have [language-design] and [language-implementation] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This edit to my question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38) suggests removing the [language-design](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) tag because "that tag is implicit - *all* questions are about language design." I included the tag because not all questions are about language design: design and implementation are different topics that are both in scope.

Should we have [language-design](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) and [language-implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-implementation) tags?

Comment: Right, a tag that is applicable to 50% of the questions is still not really valuable...